# Flapped T in the word “appetite”

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

In the word “appetite” T is between 2 vowels and it’s not flapped T according to Oxford American English dictionary. Why?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think it's because there's an exception to the "t between two vowels" rule: if the t begins a stressed syllable, it's **not** flapped.   I can think of lots of words that have a t between two vowels that isn't flapped: deter, betide, maternal...

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but I can't imagine pronouncing the word "appetite" with an unflapped "t." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping) gives an audio example between "latter" and "ladder" where unflapped "latter" sounds nearly identical to "ladder" ("appedide?") But online pronunciation examples for "appetite" for [American Engilish](https://youtu.be/_wTIX3x4Oj8) and [British English](https://youtu.be/AabzJnluxQY) are both flapped. I have no idea why OAE would say otherwise. (Curiously, I flap the "t" in all three of the examples @stangdon suggests...)

Comment: Nak, it might help if you specified *which* T in *appetite* you are talking about - the first one, the second one, or both.  I assumed you meant the last one, but it would help if you could clarify.

Comment: @JBH, I think you've got the terminology swapped.  A flapped t sounds like a d - so *flapped* "latter" sounds just like "ladder".  If you pronounced those three other words with flapped ts, they'd sound like *de-dur*, *be-died*, *ma-der-nal*.

Comment: @Juhasz That wouldn't surprise me at all... it's happened before. And it would explain why the OAE makes the claim it does.

Answer (score 1):

The first "t" in "appetite" is not flapped because flaps only occur in unstressed syllables. That syllable, "tite", has a *secondary stress*:

> /ˈa-pə-ˌtīt/
> -- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appetite)

The 'ˌ' symbol before the /tīt/ indicates a secondary stress.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for not flapping a T that is between vowels is how the vowels either side of it are pronounced. For example, a 'T' followed by a 'silent E' is not usually flapped, such as in *late, ate, plate* etc.

In the word *appetite* there are two Ts, and both are flanked by vowels, technically. But the second is followed by a 'silent e' which acts on the letter 'i', changing it into a long vowel. The letters 'ite' should therefore be considered a unit of speech, and that is why the preceding 't' is not flapped - the 'i' does not belong to that unit.

Even written rules of English commonly have exceptions, but you're referring to nothing more than a 'rule of thumb' for certain English dialects.

Comment: What do you mean by "unit of speech"? Like, a morpheme? a syllable? What are the units of speech in "latter" that allow the flap?